# Pause Manipulation when Space Bar is pushed

Tags: manipulate, animation

I have the following animation:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> 10], {i, 1, 10, 
  ControlType -> Animator}]
```

How can I pause it and play it again when I press the Space Bar like it is done for Videos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `Manipulate`, [`EventHandler`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) and [`Overlay`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html):

```
DynamicModule[{running = False}, Overlay[
 {EventHandler[Manipulate[Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> 10], 
     {i, 1, 10, Dynamic@ Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> running] &}], 
   {{"KeyDown", " "} :> (running = ! running)}], 
  Graphics[{FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> {Full, 400}]}, All, 1]]
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to use [`CellEventActions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEventActions.html) to have key events to toggle animation:

```
DynamicModule[{running = False}, 
 CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Manipulate[Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> 10], 
   {i, 1, 10, Dynamic@Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> running] &}], "Output", 
 CellEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", " "} :> (running = ! running)}]]]
```

**Note:** the mouse needs to be in the output cell for the space bar events to work.

Both methods work in version 9 / Windows 10.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot ! The first methods works perfectly for me, the second does not, but it's okay if one works ! :))

Comment: @james, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept and the bounty.